# How do I implement multicast dynamic join/prune using ns3

Tags: c++, multicast, ns-3

Is there a way to implement the dynamic prune/graft of nodes in a multicast network using ns3. The resources I could find all implements only static routing for multicast networks.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this:
http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.16/doxygen/classns3_1_1_ipv4_static_routing_helper.html#ae69a07ded3139dfd4e21bb7c10eba416

In ns-3 we set a default multicast route for the node's routing table executing `SetDefaultMulticastRoute(dev,nd)`, which as the documentation states is equivalent to executing the following:

```
    route add 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev nd
```

When setting up multicast for a linux server in the physical world, we need to have a route for the multicast addresses in the routing table. In ns-3 simulation world we have to do the same for each node we create using `SetDefaultMulticastRoute(dev,nd)`.

The static multicast routes are for routing from one LAN to another. In the real world, we need to have a router that knows how to route multicast. In the ns-3 simulation world, we need a router that knows how to route multicast. So in ns-3 we need to setup a static route from one LAN to another using `AddMulticastRoute()` that is installed on the node in the simulation that is acting as the router.

It would be nice to have an ns-3 helper that would install the Default Multicast route on a `NodeContainer` and `NetDeviceContainer`. However, the method wants one Node and its associated `NetDevice`, so you have to use a loop to set them all assuming `0..N` nodes in the `NodeContainer` are directly related to `0..N` nodes in the `NetDeviceContainer`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        Ptr<Node> sender = nodecontainer.Get (i);
        Ptr<NetDevice> senderIf = netdevicecontainer.Get (i);
        multicast.SetDefaultMulticastRoute (sender, senderIf);
    }
```

Referencing this:
http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.16/doxygen/csma-multicast_8cc_source.html

You can see how the sender and receiver of multicast packets is setup. It does include a static route between two LANs. The receiver in this example does not have a default multicast route setup. The inline comments state that all nodes will receive the multicast frame from the source - the source being the node in which we execute `SetDefaultMulticastRoute(source,sourceIf)` for.

Note that the comments for this code indicate that the source receives the multicast frame it sends.

Referencing this:
http:// www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.16/doxygen/udp-echo-server_8cc_source.html

The ns3 Application you write does the actual join to the Multicast group.

```
    78  if (m_socket == 0)
    79     {
    80       TypeId tid = TypeId::LookupByName ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory");
    81       m_socket = Socket::CreateSocket (GetNode (), tid);
    82       InetSocketAddress local = InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), m_port);
    83       m_socket->Bind (local);
    84       if (addressUtils::IsMulticast (m_local))
    85         {
    86           Ptr<UdpSocket> udpSocket = DynamicCast<UdpSocket> (m_socket);
    87           if (udpSocket)
    88             {
    89               // equivalent to setsockopt (MCAST_JOIN_GROUP)
    90               udpSocket->MulticastJoinGroup (0, m_local);
    91             }
    92           else
    93             {
    94               NS_FATAL_ERROR ("Error: Failed to join multicast group");
    95             }
    96         }
    97     }
```