# wireless Multicast in ns3 c++

Tags: c++, join, multicast, ns-3

I was trying to implement wifi multicast in ns3.But the only resources  I could find are
 ***csma-multivast.cc 
 & wimax-multicast.cc*** available in ***src*** folder.I searched many place .I couldn't use the method ***JoinMulticastGroup()*** since I am using ns3.19 version.Can anyone tell me which version supports ***JoinMulticastGroup()***   .I have looked to the solution given in [a link]
[How do I implement multicast dynamic join/prune using ns3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795069/how-do-i-implement-multicast-dynamic-join-prune-using-ns3)
Can anyone help with this